# Existence of periodic solution of a non-homogeneous ODE system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, periodic-functions

Show that the following system of ordinary differential equations
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=0.5x+2.5y-x(x^2+y^2),$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-0.5x+1.5y-y(x^2+y^2).$$
has at least one periodic solution.

I tried to find a conserved function to the system, but it seems not easy and I cannot come up with other ideas. Are there any other useful ideas to deal with such problem proving the existence of periodic solutions? Thanks!

Comment: You do not need a conserved function, you need a trapping region. With the last terms it seems sensible to transform to standard polar coordinates and explore where the radius derivative has an angle-independent sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system has the form $\newcommand{\vv}{{\vec v}}$
$$
\dot{\vv}=A\vv-r^2\vv,~~ \vv=\pmatrix{x\\y},~r=|\vv|,~A=\frac12\pmatrix{1&5\\-1&3}
$$
The stationary points of it are $\vv=0$ and the vectors of eigenpairs $(|\vv|^2,\vv)$, if the matrix had real eigenvalues.

*Claim:* There are no real eigenvalues and the origin is an outward spiral.

If you set $u=r^2=x^2+y^2$ you get
$$
\dot u=\vv^TB\vv-2u^2
\text{ with }
B=A+A^T=\pmatrix{1&2\\2&3},
$$
so that
$$
\lambda_\min u-2u^2\le \dot u\le\lambda_\max u-2u^2
$$
where the $λ_{\min,\max}$ are the eigenvalues of $B$. The left side is not helpful, however, the right side is negative at $u=\lambda_\max$.

*Claim:* This makes $0<|\vv|<\sqrt{\lambda_\max}$ a trapping region with no equilibrium points.